# My console freeze when I run my "lazy prediction" script

Tags: python, spyder

I am not sure if anyone can help me with this, so I just give it try in here :

I have tried to use the "lazypredict" package but whenever I ran it, it stuck at certain place. Originally , I thought it just took time to run the data, so I have left my computer running for 2 weeks. It keep in the same status after 2 weeks? I have tried to trim down the the data size so that the lazy prediction can be run completely, but it still freeze at the same place May I know if there is anyway I can solve this problem ?

I only got one line in my console and keep stuck at the same status for 2 weeks:

59%|█████▊    | 17/29 [13:50:35<5:34:46, 1673.91s/it]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's late but can you please tell me the shape of dataset you are using before and after trim?

Answer (score 1):

You have given us very little information to run on here, but for anyone else who struggles with this in the future, a general problem with LazyPredict regression seems to be a single model called the **Quantile Regressor**, as you can see in [this GitHub PR](https://github.com/shankarpandala/lazypredict/pull/401).

To fix it, I manually removed the problematic regression model as shown below, and then used LazyPredict as usual. If you have a different problematic model (say with the classifiers), the logic would be similar.

```
import sklearn
from lazypredict import Supervised

Supervised.removed_regressors.append("QuantileRegressor")
Supervised.REGRESSORS.remove(('QuantileRegressor', sklearn.linear_model._quantile.QuantileRegressor))
LazyRegressor = Supervised.LazyRegressor
```

I hope the maintainers merge in the PR or find an alternate fix for the issue soon, although it has been about 6 months at the time of writing.

Hope this helps. Cheers!